# Show loader % while handling multiple http requests concurrently for same API

Tags: json, angular, optimization, rxjs

I have a form with multiple posts.
User has the option to comment on one post and submit or comment on multiple posts and submit.

The problem which I'm facing is that I have just one API to save user comment.

```
for eg:- http://localhost:4200/post/postid
```

To let user know the status in case of saving all comments, is there a way to show loading with %age for each successful / failed response.

I'm currently looking to solve using Rxjs operators but other solution is also appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

This is an example of a post

```
{
  post: {
    "userId": 1,
    "postId": 1,
    "title": "Hello World",
    "body": "post body will contain large text"
    "pictures": ["1.jpg", "2.jpg"],
    "date": "01/01/1970",
    "lastModifiedDate": "01/02/1970"
  }
}
```

For storing multiple comments at once I run a loop times the count of post to push all post in an array and use forkJoin to call the API.

This works but takes a lot of time to finish because forkJoin completes only after all subscriptions have completed.

```
posts = [
  post: {
    "userId": 1,
    "postId": 1,
    "title": "Hello World",
    "body": "post body will contain large text"
    "pictures": ["1.jpg", "2.jpg"],
    "date": "01/01/1970",
    "lastModifiedDate": "01/02/1970"
  },
  post: {...}
]


let list = [];
for(let i=0; i<posts.length; i++){
  list.push({postObject});
}

forkJoin(list).subscribe(response => {
   console.log(response);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `merge` instead of `forkJoin`. See [doc](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge).

You will get the result of each call one by one.

```
yourLoaderPercentage=0;
...

merge(list).subscribe(response => {
   console.log(response);
   this.yourLoaderPercentage += 1/list.length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an observable that emits an object that represents the state of your "progress". A simple interface could look like this

```
{
  total: number;
  completed: number;
}
```

We can start the observable stream with the individual requests.  I'd use a `Subject` to push single requests through something like this:

```js
private request$ = new Subject<your type>();

makeRequest(data) {
  this.request$.next(data);
}
```

Then, we can create an observable that does your desired behavior:

- make each individual post request
- emit the desired status as requests are made and when responses are received

To achieve updating the state twice for each request (*once upon firing the request, and once when receiving the response*) we need an observable that emits twice.  We can achieve using the `startWith` operator like this:

```js
private post(data) {
  return this.http.post(data).pipe(
    map(response => ({ ...response, isComplete: true})),
    startWith({isComplete: false})
  );
}
```

We use `startWith` to immediately emit a value so we can update the overall state before the response comes back. Notice the `isComplete` flag.  It's set to `false` for the initial emission and set to `true` for the emission that occurs after the response is received. Later on we need a way to determine which property of our state object to update.

With this in mind, we can now create our observable based on the `response$` stream. We will use the `scan` operator to maintain our state.  `scan` take two parameters:

- a function that receives the prior value and the current emission
- seed value that serves as the "prior value" when handling the first emission

Each time `scan` receives an emission, it will run the function and emit the result.

```js
  requests$ = this.request$.pipe(
    mergeMap(request => this.post(request)),
    scan(({total, completed}, request) => ({
      total: total + (!request.isComplete ? 1 : 0),
      completed: completed + (request.isComplete ? 1 : 0),
    }), { total: 0, completed: 0 }),
  );
```

Explaination:

- `mergeMap` - will execute `this.post()` each time it receives an emission from `request$`, then it will emit the response. (*remember `this.post()` emits two values for each request*).
- `scan` - receives emissions from `this.post()` and runs the provided function to calculate a value based on the current emission and prior emissions. We return an object with two properties `total` and `completed`. When the emission is denoted as `isCompleted = false`, we increment the total. When `isCompleted = true` we increment the completed count.

Now, you can simply consume the `requests$` observable in the template using the `async` pipe:

```html
    <ng-container *ngIf="requests$ | async as requests">
      <progress [value]="requests.completed / requests.total"> </progress>
      <label> {{ requests.completed }} / {{ requests.total}} </label>
    </ng-container>
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-76074608?devtoolsHeight=85&file=src%2Fmain.ts) example you can play with.